# Is all data valid x86 16-bit machine code?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, machine-code

Executing `ndisasm /dev/urandom` seems to never give me any errors. This suggests that I am either very lucky or all bytes really disassemble into 16-bit assembler.

I am facing an actual issue because I want to know if I can rely on this behavior to test my disassembler.

Comment: Related but not duplicate: [How to tell if a binary sequence is x86 machine code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12027405/309483)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540922/x86-assember-illegal-opcode-0xff-7-under-windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [effect of undefined opcodes on the (original) Intel 8086/88](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811803/effect-of-undefined-opcodes-on-the-original-intel-8086-88)

Comment: EF C6 BF 08 00 00 00 isn't valid x86 according to olly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is not all valid, cause I think `ndisasm` will output lines like `db 0x82` when it doesn't match an instruction. Lines like that are there.